# SDL_Texture doesn't get drawn in second instance

Tags: c++, sdl-2

main.cpp

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

//Constants
bool isFullscreen = false;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH  = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const char *GAME_NAME = "Alex's RPG Game | Version 2";

//Game
Game *game = nullptr; //Game is null --> nullpointer


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //Ignore the arguments

    std::cout << "Starting game" << std::endl;

    game = new Game();

    game->init(GAME_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    while (game->isGameRunning()){
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }

    game->destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

game.cpp:

```
Game::Game() {
    isRunning = false;
    screen = new SplashScreen(getGame());
}

Game::~Game() {
    //Empty deconstructor
}

void Game::init(const char *title, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, Uint32 flag) {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {

        std::cout << "Subsystems are running..." << std::endl;

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xPos, yPos, width, height, flag);

        if (window) {
            std::cout << "Window created" << std::endl;
        }

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);


        if (renderer) {
            //Draw a black background
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            std::cout << "Renderer created" << std::endl;
        }

        screen->create(renderer);

        std::cout << "Game successful initiated" << std::endl;
        isRunning = true;


    } else {
        isRunning = false;
    }

}

void Game::render() {

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    screen->render(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::destroy() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Game successful destroyed" << std::endl;
}

void Game::update() {
    screen->update();
}

void Game::handleEvents() {

    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

bool Game::isGameRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}

void Game::setScreen(IScreen *screen1) {
    screen = screen1;
}
```

game.h

```
class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, Uint32 flag);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void setScreen(IScreen *screen1);
    void destroy();

    Game* getGame(){
        return this;
    }

    bool isGameRunning();

private:
    bool isRunning;

    //Define a pointer to a window and a renderer
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Event event;

    IScreen *screen;

};
```

SplashScreen.h

```
class SplashScreen: public IScreen{
public:

    explicit SplashScreen(Game *game);
    ~SplashScreen();

    void render(SDL_Renderer *renderer) override;
    void update() override;
    void create(SDL_Renderer *renderer) override;

private:
    SDL_Texture *texture;
    SDL_Rect rect;

    Game *game;

    int time = 0;

};
```

SplashScreen.cpp class being an implementation of the IScreen

```
SplashScreen::SplashScreen(Game *game1){

    //Constructor
    game = game1;
}

SplashScreen::~SplashScreen(){

    //Deconstructor

}

void SplashScreen::update() {
    // Update the screen

    if(SDL_GetTicks() > 5000 + time){
        game->setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
    }

}

void SplashScreen::render(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);

}


void SplashScreen::create(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    texture = TextureManager::loadTexture("player.png", renderer);

    rect.x = 50;
    rect.y = 50;
    rect.h = 32;
    rect.w = 32;

    time = SDL_GetTicks();

}
```

MenuScreen.h

```
class MenuScreen: public IScreen{
public:

    explicit MenuScreen(Game *game1);
    ~MenuScreen();

    void render(SDL_Renderer *renderer) override;
    void update() override;
    void create(SDL_Renderer *renderer) override;

private:
    SDL_Texture *tex;
    SDL_Rect rect;

    Game *game;

};
```

MenuScreen.cpp class also being an implementation of the IScreen:

```
MenuScreen::MenuScreen(Game *game1) {
    game = game1;
}

MenuScreen::~MenuScreen() {

}

void MenuScreen::update() {
    std::cout << "Why can't it render" << std::endl;
}

void MenuScreen::render(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    std::cout << "Why can't it render" << std::endl;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, nullptr, &rect);

}

void MenuScreen::create(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    tex = TextureManager::loadTexture("test.png", renderer);

    rect.x = 100;
    rect.y = 100;
    rect.h = 32;
    rect.w = 32;

}
```

Both implementations are equal except their class name and the path to the image file. Both files (test.png (green image) and player.png (blue image)) exist and can be loaded successful. When I run the program, player.png is rendered in the
SplashScreen class.
But when I change the screen in the game class from SplashScreen to MenuScreen, all the MenuScreen-functions are called, but the texture doesn't get rendered.
SDL_GetError() does not return any error, I don't get any exception, the texture and the renderer are not null (already checked) and I can't see anything on the screen (It is a black screen).
If everything would work correctly, you should see a colored square on the screen.

**Update:**

TextureManager.cpp

```
SDL_Texture *TextureManager::loadTexture(const char *path, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(path);
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return texture;
}
```

IScreen.h

```
#include "SDL.h"

class IScreen{
public:

    virtual void create(SDL_Renderer *renderer) = 0;

    virtual void render(SDL_Renderer *renderer) = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;


};
```

Comment: In `void SplashScreen::render()` you have this `rect` variable. Is it a class variable or a local one? Also, `delete` your `Game` object at the end of `main(int argc, char * argv[])`, avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @atmostmediocre The rect is a class variable (SDL_Rect). The game get's destroyed, with it's own function, but I didn't pasted it, to keep the code clear

Comment: What's in `TextureManager`?

Comment: I'm guessing the `screen` variable is a `SplashScreen`. You'd need another variable, this time `MenuScreen` and actually display it, because in the `Game::render()` menuscreen is never drawn

Comment: Also, why use `SDL_SetRenderTarget` in MenuScreen? And can you confirm your `tex` variable isn't null when you call `MenuScreen::render`?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau You can see it in the updates code. It is a function that get's a path and the renderer, creates a texture from a surface and returns it. 2.) If I put a if(tex == NULL) {SDL_Quit()}, the quit-statement is never called. 3.) I tried to solve with SetRenderTarget, buit I didn't worked and it didn't work.

Comment: @atmostmediocre The screen varibale is an object of the IScreen class. Both, SplashScreen and MenuScreen, are child of it. The functions gets called, because it prints a text, if a put a cout statement into the render-method.

Comment: A screen owns a game, and a game owns a screen? Pardon me, but that's a strange architecture. Also, you're leaking a SplashScreen when you replace the pointer of the screen with a new MenuScreen (essentially, you lose the SplashScreen pointer, and can't delete it). And after that, while you're in the middle of a SpashScreen `update`, you call a MenuScreen `render`. That probably Not Good™. Another question : I can't see how `MenuScreen::create` could be called. You call the constructor, but never the `create` method. When is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never call the `MenuScreen::create` method, so your `SDL_Texture` is never created.

You said in a comment that you checked the value of the attribute `tex` and that it's not null, but since it's not initialized in the constructor, it probably contains a random value.

---

These are more general comments than directly related to your problem, but like I said in a comment, you should really change your program architecture, because you have a lot of inherent bugs coming from it. For example, you're leaking a SplashScreen object when you switch the screen pointer to that of a MenuScreen.

You should take a look at a good Game State Engine in C++, and manage the splash screen, the menu, and any other game states as a State in a State Engine. For example, [this tutorial](http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/) has a good basic state machine implementation.

Comment: I figured it out, that I only was missing to call screen->create(); when I set a new screen in the game class.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help. You can accept my answer if it was your problem.

I would recommend heeding my architecture advice, though. I've been designing game engines for a long time, and I can instantly tell that you're going to have problems down the road.

Comment: I will definitely do some changes. My initial design was based on an engine design, but now I think, that it not a good decision.